# Python to Shell Script?

Tags: shell, python

How can I convert this simple python code to Shell script?

```
   import time
   import sys
   cur_time = int(time.time()*1000)
   print cur_time
   sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just multiplying the seconds since epoch by 1000 (with some added nanosecond precision).

You can do:

```
$(($(date '+%s') * 1000))
```

With the nanosecond precision, in`zsh`:

```
$(($(date '+%s.%N') * 1000))
```

Precision to 2 decimal points, in `zsh`:

```
printf '%.2f\n' $(($(date '+%s.%N') * 1000))
```

As `bash` (and other shells) does not support floating point arithmetic, you can use `bc` instead.

**Example:**

```
% echo $(($(date '+%s') * 1000))
1462194433000

% echo $(($(date '+%s.%N') * 1000))
1462194596950.2983

% printf '%.2f\n' $(($(date '+%s.%N') * 1000))
1462194696479.11
```

Comment: `date +%s` delivers:
`%s`

Comment: This does not change things. A more portable way to print the current time_t value is to run `awk 'BEGIN{srand();  print srand() }'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test [scrptine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scriptine).I think it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pemission

```
 chmod +x file
```

and add in the first line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If I am correct it's used to call without the preceding language. The script then calls the language's interpreter to run the code inside the script